# PHP Database Filter

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to have a simple select box that filters the database. I have successfully filled the database with all vallues on pageload, however I cant seem to get over the final hurdle of applying the filter. Also, once I have clicked the filter button, is it possible for the select text to stay at the text rather than returning to the default text?

[NOTE: I have pretty URL's enabled hence the no .php at the end]

The code is as followed:

```
            <?php 

            $query = "SELECT * FROM Events";
            echo $Type;

            if (isset($_POST['filter'])) {

                $Type = $_POST['value'];

                $query .= " WHERE Type = '{$Type}'";

            }               

            $result = mysql_query($query);

            ?>                      

            <form action='/events' method="post" name="form_filter" >
                <select class="eventList">
                    <option value="EVENT1">EVENT1</option>
                    <option value="EVENT2">EVENT2</option>
                    <option value="EVENT3">EVENT3</option>
                    <option value="EVENT4">EVENT4</option>
                    <option value="EVENT5">EVENT5</option>
                    <option value="EVENT6">EVENT6</option>
                    <input type="submit" name="filter" value="Filter">                      
                </select>

            </form> 

            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-curved">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><b>Date</b></th>
                        <th><b>Event Name</b></th>
                        <th><b>Type</b></th>
                        <th><b>Region</b></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>                 

                <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $Date = $row['Date']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $Name = $row['Name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $Type = $row['Type']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $Region = $row['Region']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: (1) form inputs need a name attribute - `<select name="eventList" class="eventList">` which you then get in php - `$Type = $_POST['eventList'];`.  (2) you should sanitize any data that you add to your query - `$Type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['eventList']). (3) why is your submit button `<input type="submit" name="filter" value="Filter">` nested inside your `<select>`? (4) take the time to update from `mysql` to `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: @Sean Thanks for the informative message - even with all the changes it isnt working. I click the filter button and it just returns to the same page without any changes to the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code as follow

```
<?php 

        $query = "SELECT * FROM Events";
        echo $Type;

        if (isset($_POST)) {

            $Type = $_POST['event'];

            $query .= " WHERE Type = '{$Type}'";

        }               

        $result = mysql_query($query);

        ?>                      

        <form action='/events' method="post" name="form_filter" >
            <select class="eventList" name="event">
                <option value="EVENT1" <?php echo ($Type=="EVENT1")?'selected="selected"':'';?>>EVENT1</option>
                <option value="EVENT2" <?php echo ($Type=="EVENT2")?'selected="selected"':'';?>>EVENT2</option>
                <option value="EVENT3" <?php echo ($Type=="EVENT3")?'selected="selected"':'';?>>EVENT3</option>
                <option value="EVENT4" <?php echo ($Type=="EVENT4")?'selected="selected"':'';?>>EVENT4</option>
                <option value="EVENT5" <?php echo ($Type=="EVENT5")?'selected="selected"':'';?>>EVENT5</option>
                <option value="EVENT6" <?php echo ($Type=="EVENT6")?'selected="selected"':'';?>>EVENT6</option>
                <input type="submit" name="filter" value="Filter">                      
            </select>

        </form> 

        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-curved">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><b>Date</b></th>
                    <th><b>Event Name</b></th>
                    <th><b>Type</b></th>
                    <th><b>Region</b></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>                 

            <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $Date = $row['Date']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $Name = $row['Name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $Type = $row['Type']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $Region = $row['Region']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

i have update this line
`if (isset($_POST)) {

and added the select name and code list code

```
 $Type =$_POST['event'];
<select class="eventList" name="event">
<option value="EVENT1" <?php echo ($Type=="EVENT1")?'selected="selected"':'';?>>EVENT1</option>
```

Comment: this does not fix the OPs issue, which is the `<select>` does not have a name attribute, so all your `echo ($Type=="...")` will never work in addition to their db filtering not working

Comment: i have edited the code you are right, i have realized after posting

Comment: This works, however how can I edit this so that it shows all results when the page is first loaded?

Comment: it should show results when page loaded first time, but after you post the page it will show filter results, if its not the case let me know i will send you the fix

Answer (score 2):

Your `<select>` does not have a name:

```
<select class="eventList" name="event">
```

Use that name as index in the `$_POST` array:

```
$Type = $_POST['event'];
```